# Python's PIL image library is not working

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a strange error when trying to use Pillow to save an image in my [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) admin...

```
from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging
```

#### File Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from string import join
import os
from PIL.Image import core as _imaging
from PIL import Image as PImage
from my_site.settings import MEDIA_ROOT

class Image(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True, null=True)
    image       = models.FileField(upload_to="images/")
    created     = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    width       = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    height      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    category    = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        im = PImage.open(os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, self.image.name))
        self.width, self.height = im.size
        super(Image, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

#### File Admin.py

```
class GenericImageAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display    = ["__unicode__", "title", "created", "thumbnail"]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()

admin.site.register(GenericImage, GenericImageAdmin)
```

The weirdest part is I get the same error when I remove

```
from PIL.Image import core as _imaging
```

I'm using [Pillow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library), not the old [PIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library). What is the deal?

Comment: `from PIL import _imaging as core` is not the same as `from PIL.Image import core as _imaging`. It's not completely clear which code is erroring... If you run python directly in the shell/command line where you're running django from, can you recreate the error by doing the import manually? If so can you post that (what you're typing and the resulting error and stacktrace)?

Comment: `In [4]: from PIL import Image
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0f6709e38f49> in <module>()
----> 1 from PIL import Image

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py in <module>()
 
---> 63     from PIL import _imaging as core
     
64     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
     
65         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "

ImportError: cannot import name _imaging`

Comment: worst part is, I did exactly what the tutorial says to do...http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html

I uninstalled PIL already, I just doublechecked

Comment: I get the same error when I comment out the overriding

`from PIL.Image import core as _imaging`

Comment: Duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720968/pil-importerror-the-imaging-extension-was-built-for-another-version-of-pillow

Comment: I'm getting a diff error message, but I will try out the solution there as well

Comment: @m9_psy, sadly that solution didn't work. I uninstalled and reinstalled as suggested. The only piece of code exposed is

`from PIL import Image as PImage`

causing a very frustrating

`from PIL import _imaging as core
ImportError: cannot import name _imaging`

Comment: Ref: http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html, this part of the stack trace "63 from PIL import _imaging as core" looks suspicious. The docs say that `_imaging` isn't part of Pillow, and they also say that PIL and Pillow aren't compatible. Is it possible you have (the original) PIL installed, or you have installed PIllow over the top of PIL? Ref the actual Pillow code that is giving you the error: https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/PIL/Image.py#L63 It looks like you installation of Pillow is probably broken in some unexpected way.

Comment: All I can suggest is trying to uninstall both Pillow and PIL, then manually deleting the /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL directory, and then trying a fresh install. You might also have more luck installing Pillow into a clean virtual environment in case there is something else in your system python install that is conflicting with it.