# Can't import PIL library

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-imaging-library

I've installed pillow for python 3 on my macbook successfully. But I still can't use PIL library. I tried uninstalling and installing it again. I've also tried `import Image`  without `from PIL` as well. I do not have PIL installed, though. It says

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from
>   versions: )

```
from PIL import Image  


--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-4-b7f01c2f8cfe> in <module>()
----> 1 from PIL import Image

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/Image.py in <module>()
     58     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     59     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 60     from . import _imaging as core
     61     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
     62         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime   Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)   Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib  in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib
```

Comment: Did you install the module via pip or compiled the source yourself? It seems you maybe missing a dependency.

Comment: I installed it via pip.

Comment: this is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26720968/pil-importerror-the-imaging-extension-was-built-for-another-version-of-pillow

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Anaconda`, you may try:

```
conda install Pillow
```

because this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Pil is depricated and replaced by pillow. Pillow is the official fork of PIL

Install using pip or how you usually do it.

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/5.1.x/index.html