# Problem with importing Image from PIL in python

Tags: python-3.x

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
```

THE ERROR SHOWN IS :

```
ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow 
or 
PIL:
Core version: 3.0.0
Pillow version: 5.1.0
```

I am running this on jupyter notebook on anaconda. I tried installing pillow through both pip and conda and I am still not able import the mentioned package. Am I missing out on any fundamental thing over here?

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/26720968/2570277

Comment: I referred to that. It is not working.

Comment: what version of python are you running?

Comment: The version is python 3.5