# Wierd pillow version conflict ( Python 3.7.9 )

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, python-3.7

I'm having a very weird pillow version conflict on python 3.7.9
The only command I'm running on my Jupyter notebook cell is

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
Core version: "9.2.0"
Pillow version: 9.2.0
```

The Core version and Pillow version are matching, I have no clue where's the error. Maybe those quotation marks shouldn't be there? Every package I downloaded was always through Conda in a virtual env, not sure what the problem is/how could this have happened

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd recommend you upgrade `numpy`, `pil` or `pillow`, `scipy` packages. Just run `pip install -U <package_name>` for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with a fresh environment, with all packages at their newest version. It might be a bug. A quick fix is to modify the file which throws the error, which you can e.g. find at `C:\user\miniconda3\envs\plotting\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py`.

At line 102, replace

```
    if __version__ != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None):
    raise ImportError(
        "The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:\n"
        f"Core version: {getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None)}\n"
        f"Pillow version: {__version__}"
    )
```

with

```
    if __version__ != getattr(core, "PILLOW_VERSION", None).replace('"', ''):
    raise ImportError(
        "The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:\n"
        f"Core version: {getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None)}\n"
        f"Pillow version: {__version__}"
    )
```

By removing the quotations marks, the check will pass.

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking of just using a replace on the quotation marks, but was worried this might create wierd conflicts. I tried upvoting but I don't think I have enough SO points to vote ;-;

Comment: See also [Pillow issue 6437: import PIL.Image double quotes for Core version: "9.2.0"](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6437). Pay attention to [@Bartoli comment](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6437#issuecomment-1189077129)

Answer (score 0):

If someone still needs to use `pillow==9.2.0`, such might want to note the following.

@chrissi_gsa workaround is viable.
However, on the basis of the wise advice given by @hugo to the [answer in a related SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804968/20107918), I'll recommend following the uninstall and installing approach (applicable version or an applicable patch). In essence, follow the same '*logical approach*' proffer in [this `pillow` issue #6862](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6862).

If one is using `Notebook`, kindly restart the `kernel`, otherwise you might be getting the `pillow` import error similar to the one below:

```py
ImportError: The _imaging extension was built for another version of Pillow or PIL:
Core version: 10.0.0
Pillow version: 9.4.0
```